# Can't connect to web hosted MySQL database

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am using VB.NET to connect to a MySQL database.

I have the following code:

```vb
Public Function getListOfDatabase() As List(Of String)
    Dim SQL As String = "select * from covenusers"

    Dim output As New List(Of String)()

    ' Set the connection string in the Solutions Explorer/Properties/Settings object (double-click)

    Using cn = New MySqlConnection("Server=server33.web-
hosting.com;Port=3306;Database=dbname;Uid=dbusername;
Pwd=password123;")
        Using cmd = New MySqlCommand(SQL, cn)

            cn.Open() 'this is where it breaks

            ' do stuff
        End Using
    End Using

    Return output

End Function
```

I'm using `Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient` for the MySQL handling. I get the exception: `Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.`

I know my server address, username, database name, and password are all correct. What exactly am I connecting to here? Does it go through SSH or something else?

Comment: Is that the real host name?  Most of free web hosts dont allow you to connect directly.  Consult the documentation to be sure and see what is required in this case.

Comment: have you tried to connect through a database management tool?

Comment: I have paid hosting @Plutonix.

Comment: Ask tech support for your hosting service. You may have to enable access to your MySql server explicitly from outside your hosting service’s local network.  And, don’t post real machine names, usernames, or passwords on SO. Change that password **now**.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently shared hosts do not allow you to connect to the MySQL database directly. I had to set up a SSHClient using Renci.SSHClient (google it) and port forward my database through that. What a pain smh

Hopefully this will help someone having the same issue.